# Proving an identity used in general relativity

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, general-relativity

I need to prove the following identity for scalar field ($\phi:M\rightarrow R$) in curved spacetime without torsion called $M$

$\nabla_{\mu}[\Box \phi \nabla^{\mu}\phi-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^{\mu}(\nabla \phi)^{2}]=(\Box \phi)^{2}-
R_{\mu\nu}\nabla^{\mu}\phi\nabla^{\nu}\phi- \nabla^{\mu}\nabla^{\nu}\phi \nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}\phi$.

I opened up the total derivative and the term $(\Box \phi)^{2}$ appears but the others I cannot get the right combination. I tried to use the following  identity to make appears the terms $R_{\mu\nu}\nabla^{\mu}\phi\nabla^{\nu}\phi$, namely, $[\nabla_\mu, \nabla_\nu]X_{\alpha}=-R^{\kappa}_{\alpha\mu\nu}X_{\kappa}$, but I got stuck at some point, and the  third term does not appear at all.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is your left-most term missing a $\phi $?

Comment: Would the Bianchi identity be of some help?

Comment: Dear Michael, yes there was a typo.

Comment: Dear Sylvain, I tried to use the Bianchi identity but I could not get the right answer.

Comment: “Used in general relativity” suggests that you’ve seen someone else use this before, in which case it’d be helpful to cite that source, and they’ve probably provided a name or a citation for the identity.

Comment: This kind of trick  appears in Hordensky  theory.

Answer (score 6):

This is the differential form of the Reilly formula. It holds for a function on any pseudo-Riemannian manifold. (Robert C. Reilly. *Applications of the Hessian operator in a Riemannian manifold*, Indiana Univ. Math. J. **26** (1977), no. 3, 459–472, doi:[10.1512/iumj.1977.26.26036](https://doi.org/10.1512/iumj.1977.26.26036))

Use the product rule to say
$$(\Delta f)^2=\operatorname{div}(\Delta f\cdot\nabla f)-\langle\nabla f,\nabla\Delta f\rangle.$$
Use the commutation formula for covariant derivatives to replace the last term by
$$\langle\nabla f,\nabla\Delta f\rangle=\langle\nabla f,\Delta\nabla f\rangle-\operatorname{Ric}(\nabla f,\nabla f).$$
Use the product rule to replace the second to last term by
$$\langle\nabla f,\Delta\nabla f\rangle=\operatorname{div}\big(\nabla^2f(\nabla f,\cdot)\big)-|\nabla\nabla f|^2.$$
Finally $\nabla^2f(\nabla f,\cdot)=\frac{1}{2}\nabla|\nabla f|^2$. This gives your formula.

**Edit**. As pointed out by Jeffrey Case below, this also follows from the Bochner formula
$$\frac{1}{2}\Delta|\nabla f|^2=|\nabla\nabla f|^2+\langle\nabla\Delta f,\nabla f\rangle+\operatorname{Ric}(\nabla f,\nabla f),$$
where you just need to use the very first line above to replace the middle term on the RHS. The proof of the Bochner formula is by the other lines above

Comment: I think it is better to call this (a variant of) the [Bochner formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_formula).  The formula in the original post will (essentially) appear in any textbook under this name.  "Reilly formula" usually refers to the result after integrating on a manifold with boundary and performing further algebraic manipulations on the boundary.

Comment: That's fair. When I called it the Reilly formula I was thinking of the case of a closed manifold

Comment: Dear Quarto Bendir, thank you so much for your help and specially for proving the mathematical reference.